# Sending broadcast from ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, android

When I try to send any action from `ScheduledExecutorService` using `LocalBroadcastManager` it seems that real action hasn't been sent(or hasn't been delivered). Here is code example:

```
public class SomeService extends IntentService {
    private static final String TAG = SomeService.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String ACTION = "some-action";

    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduledTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    public SomeService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals("scheduled_action")) {
            scheduledTaskExecutor.schedule(new ScheduledAction(ACTION), 10, SECONDS);
        } else if (action.equals("send_it_now")) {
            sendAction(ACTION);
        }
    }

    private void sendAction(String action) {
        Log.d(TAG, "send action [" + action + "]");
        Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(SomeService.this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    // it also could be Callable, but effect is pretty the same
    private class ScheduledAction implements Runnable {
        final String action;

        ScheduledAction(String action) {
            this.action = action;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            sendAction(action);
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on incomming action, service sends `ACTION` right away or send it after 10 seconds. This is activity which is subscribed for `ACTION`:

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = SomeActivity.class.getName();
    private BroadcastReceiver actionReceiver = new ActionReceiver();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(SomeService.ACTION);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(actionReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(actionReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private class ActionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            Log.d(TAG, "received action [" + action + "]");
        }
    }
}
```

In case of `send_it_now` everything works as expected:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(..., SomeService.class);
intent.setAction("send_it_now");
startService(intent);
```

I see appropriate messages printed to the logcat:

```
...
SomeService send action [some-action]
SomeActivity received action [some-action] 
...
```

But when I try to use `scheduled_action`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(..., SomeService.class);
intent.setAction("scheduled_action");
startService(intent);
```

I see action was sent, but it was not received in the activity:

```
...
SomeService send action [some-action]
...
```

So, can anybody tell explain what's wrong with this code or at least show the direction where I can find explanations?

*Some updates. If I use [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and [TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) for the same purpose I used [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) and [ScheduledFuture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html) - it works!*

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not on the UI-thread, try this:

<strike>`public void run()
    {
        Looper.prepare();
        sendAction(action);
        Looper.loop();
    }`</strike>

```
public void run()
{
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>()
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            sendAction(action);
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Comment: I guess that it shouldn't depend on UI thread. In any case, I've checked it, doesn't help.